# allowing users to change the order of a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I've only ever used a static default scope for my projects and my latest one I wanted to create a dynamic scope feature, where the user can click a button or use a dropdown menu to change the order they view a list.

so far I've come across a few methods like using unscoping and setting a new scope, and seen reorder. I'm looking at the docs but I also am unsure of how to make a user be able to choose. Would I use something like Link_to, or button_to in the corresponding HTML.erb file?

in my `post.rb` file it'd look like this

```
default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { reorder(title: :asc) }
scope :ordered_by_reverse_created_at, -> { reorder(created_at: :ASC)}
```

I added those other scopes under the default because I assumed one would set the scopes they wanted and the view would call/activate them once a user clicks or chooses it from the rendered page.

in my `post_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

in my `index.html.erb` the view

I have the list of posts rendered this way, if it won't work with what I want to do can someone show me a better way to do it?

```
# <some way for user to choose those defined scopes and render the new page would go here> 
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">
        <%= link_to post.title, post %>
        <small> <%=  post.body %> </small>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this:

1. purely front end, use js. You can use some existing js plugin with sorting abilities if you don't feel like writing your own (e.g. DataTables). You'll probably need to make a table with the different attributes available for this to work.
2. back end, use ajax. Write your own or use something like filterrific, which uses scopes for filtering and sorting.